# Getting __file__ from calling script

Tags: python, path

I have a dozen scripts where I'm repeating this

```
# caller.py
THIS_FILE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
relative_path = lambda *x: os.path.join(THIS_FILE_DIR, *x)
```

I'd like to move this into a module as follows:

```
# module.py
def relative_path(*x):
    this_file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    return os.path.join(this_file_dir, *x)
```

However I'd like to get `__file__` in the scope of the calling script (`caller.py`) rather than the module (`module.py`) itself. Is there a way to do this without having the calling script pass in `__file__` (so my `relative_path()` method only needs `*x`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for an imported function to access global variables of the module where it [function] is imported.

`relative_path()` function can not access `__file__` of `caller.py`.

You may pass it as a parameter:

```
def relative_path(*x, __file__):
    this_file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    return os.path.join(this_file_dir, *x)
```

Answer (score 3):

It actually is possible. You can get path of caller like this

```
import inspect

def relative_path(*x):
    caller_path = inspect.stack()[1].filename
```

You then have string of absolute path (recommend using pathlib instead of os if necessary)

Passing **file** is not necessary and can be confusing...

Comment: Although beware of negative performance impact. For me it took 0.3 seconds, which make is almost unusable, except of some very specific use case...

Comment: I'm not seeing this performance impact here, execution of a simple script calling into a shared component that uses `inspect.stack()` runs in ~0.05 seconds, even if the shared component is not pre-compiled yet.